# C# Pass Object With Generic Property To Method

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a class and interface that has a property that is a generic

```
public interface IRequest<T>
{
    T RequestDetails {get; set;}
    int RequestID {get; set;}
}

public class SampleRequest<T> : IRequest<T>
{
    private T _details;
    private int _requestID;
    public T RequestDetails {get => _details; set => _details = value;}
    public int RequestID {get => _requestID; set => _requestID = value;}
}
```

What I would like to do is pass an instance of the class to a function and process information based on `RequestID`, depending on the value of `RequestID` I'm expecting `T` to be a specific Type.

```
public void SampleMethod(SampleRequest request)
{
    switch (request.RequestID)
    {
        case 1:
            // Verify T is correct Type
            break;
        case 2:
            // Verify T is correct Type
            break;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that I haven't supplied a Type for `SampleRequest` on `SampleMethod`.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You need to make the method generic `SampleMethod<T>(SampleRequest<T> request)`

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. If you have to use a switch to deal with `T` differently in each case, generics aren't the right solution.

Comment: `depending on the value of RequestID I'm expecting T to be a specific Type`  I agree with madreflection.  Based on the quoted statement from the question, I also think generics are not the ideal solution here.

Comment: I would agree with the others, just make methods for each type `public void SampleMethod(SampleRequest<int> request)` etc. Or just check the type directly rather than using this RequestID

Comment: I can't accept comments as answers, but making SampleMethod<T>(SampleRequest<T> request) does the job that I need with a little bit of rejigging of the code that is calling. Thanks @juharr.